# What was the original scoring system of Australian rules football?

Tags: rules, history, australian-rules-football

The Wikipedia article of the [Australian Football League (AFL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Football_League) states:

> [The VFL] made several innovations early on to entice the public's interest, including [...] the formal establishment of the modern scoring system, in which six points are awarded for a goal and one point for a behind.

It doesn't, however, specify what the *original* scoring system was, the one the modern scoring system replaced. Doing my own research on Google hasn't come up with anything useful either.

**What was/were the scoring system(s) of Australian rules football before the modern scoring system?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of the mid 19th century behinds did not award any points, they simply turned the ball over to the opposing team. The "modern scoring system" simply means behinds also counting as a (minor) score, rather than goals being the sole scoring opportunity.

Comment: Are there any backups for this? Where have you found that information please?

Comment: [Laws of Australian Rules Football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Australian_rules_football) seems to be a good reference here, particularly the second bullet under [Australasian Rules of 1890](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_Australian_rules_football#Australasian_Rules_of_1890): "6 points for a goal, 1 for a behind – previously, only goals counted.".

Comment: @PhilipKendall maybe add to the answer?